# jQuery optgroups show/hide

Tags: jquery

I'm using this jquery plugin 
http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/
I have several optgroups for this application, some of which have options of more than 50 to go with an optgroup. Is there a way to be able to hide an optgroup when the user clicks on the heading?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".ui-multiselect-optgroup-label").click(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil(".ui-multiselect-optgroup-label").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. I had to add a few things in the JS to make sure the items in the optgroup weren't checked when you clicked the header, but that did the job.

Comment: Anyone else notice that by checking the checkboxes, the DOM isn't updating with the event?

Comment: @Chris I know it's not probable that you'll ever revisit this question but if you do, kindly select this as the accepted answer. Thanks!